# Fast save\load big data

Tags: c#, .net, bigdata

I have the following class:

```
public class HPChartGraphPoint
{
    public int Keyword { get; set; }
    public List<long> Points { get; set; }

    public HPChartGraphPoint()
    {
        Points = new List<long>();
    }


    public string SerializeToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(Keyword);
        sb.Append(":");

        for (int i = 0; i < Points.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(Points[i]);
            sb.Append(":");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static HPChartGraphPoint DesirializeFromString(string str)
    {
        var splitter = str.Split(new[]{":"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

        var retPoint = new HPChartGraphPoint();

        retPoint.Keyword = splitter[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < splitter.Length; i++)
        {
            retPoint.Points.Add(splitter[i]);
        }

        return retPoint;
    }


}
```

i need to store and load a collection List with millions elements. How to do it fast and memory efficient?

EDIT:

Here is code for storing

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
                for (int i = 0; i < HPChartGraphPointCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(HPChartGraphPointCollection[i].SerializeToString());
                }

}
```

Comment: have you measured performance of your code block on large data set? What is the execution time? Which time is appropriate for you?

Comment: @sll I just started storing data a hour ago or something and it is still working. Output file size >20gb. So...i want do it much more faster.

Comment: are you storing/loading from a database?

Comment: @c0deNinja No, im using files. See update.

Comment: Is it important to have text-based serialization, would you consider switching to binary formats?

Comment: @alexm It is not important. Where i can read about binary serialization?

Comment: From a memory perspective why are you loading a collection of HPChartGraphPoint (HPChartGraphPointCollection) rather than processing one at a time?  And did you try writing the Point[i] : directly to file than writing to string and then writing the string to file?  And I hope you have some contiguous disk space available.

Answer (score 0):

Binary format could be more compact and easier to read/parse than text.

You could use light-weight stream wrappers: [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).